# Question Getting selected as "Hot Question" - we get any badges or reputation?

Tags: discussion, hot-questions

Do we get any kind of Badge or Reputation when our question is selected as a "Hot Question"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, at least not directly.

But it's reasonable that if a question is featured as a "Hot Question", a lot more people will see and vote it, so it will naturally gain more reputation and badges.

Comment: okay. and by the way are you really into Yahoo Answers?

Comment: @RishabhPoddar Yes I am, Stack Exchange is great when you are looking for quality answers, but nothing beats Yahoo Answers when you are looking for some cheap laughs. And there's nothing wrong with looking for some cheap laughs once in a while...

Comment: you are damn correct. I too used yahoo answers, but recently my account was blocked by yahoo because I posted, "Post this question on stackexchange.com" in a few places.

Comment: @RishabhPoddar Ah, don't do that. It's nice to direct people here once in a while, but if you do it aggressively you are a spammer.